# Golang Interface to struct conversion giving error

Tags: json, go, struct

I have an json as a string of following format:

```
{"add": [{"var": ["100"]}, "200"]}
```

Here the key 'add' is not a constant value for all the jsons. In some cases, it can be 'minus', 'multiply' etc.
The value of that key is an array. In this case [{"var": ["100"]}, "200"]. This means that the 100 should be added to existing value 200.

I am trying to parse this expression. Since the main key(in this case 'add') is not a constant, I cannot convert into a struct. So, I converted it to a json object by following way:

```
type mathExpVar struct {
    valueVar []string `json:"var"`
}
var mathExpJson map[string][]interface{}
var input = "{\"add\": [{\"var\": [\"100\"]}, \"200\"]}"
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &mathExpJson)
for operator, values := range mathExpJson{
    vals, ok := values[0].(mathExpVar) // here values[0] will be {"var": ["100"]}
    if !ok{
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here 'ok' is always returning false. I am not sure why. There is no additional error message for me to check why this is failing. Could someone help me in resolving this?

Link to go playground for the same: **https://go.dev/play/p/POfQmEoPbjD**

Comment: `valueVar` is unexported, export it - upper case `ValueVar`

Comment: @Inian Thank you for your answer but this is still not working. Please check https://go.dev/play/p/uA1dzsL5Gyi.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/Gsg5s5yFnx0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the entire structure of the parsed json value will be stored in nested `map[string]interface{}`(json object) or `[]interface{}`(json array) types.

In the line:

```
vals, ok := values[0].(mathExpVar)
```

`values[0]` would be of type `map[string]interface{}`, which cannot be asserted to `mathExpVar`, which is a struct, an entirely different datatype.

You need to type assert to `map[string]interface{}` first, then do this in each nested level as you go forward:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type mathExpVar struct {
        valueVar []string `json:"var"`
    }
    var mathExpJson map[string][]interface{}
    var input = "{\"add\": [{\"var\": [\"100\"]}, \"200\"]}"
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &mathExpJson)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in unmarshalling")
    }
    for _, values := range mathExpJson {
        var vals mathExpVar
        valMap, ok := values[0].(map[string]interface{})
        if ok {
            varSlice, ok := valMap["var"].([]interface{})
            if ok {
                for _, v := range varSlice {
                    nv, ok := v.(string)
                    if ok {
                        vals.valueVar = append(vals.valueVar, nv)
                    } else {
                        fmt.Printf("%T\n", v)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("%T\n", valMap["var"])
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%T\n", values[0])
        }
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", vals)
    }
}
```

See: https://go.dev/play/p/Ot_9IZr4pwM

For more on interfaces and go reflection, check out: https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection

Comment: Can you share why type of values[0] is 'map[string]interface{}', not just 'interface{}'. From my understanding, it should be 'interface{}' based on declaration - var mathExpJson map[string][]interface{}.

Comment: @insanePi `values[0]` is indeed of type `interface{}` as per the declaration. But `interface{}` is only the static type. The **dynamic** type of `value[0]` is going to be a non-interface type, assigned *by the json unmarshaler* as per its own documentation, which states that json objects like `{"var":["100"]}` when unmarshaled into `interface{}` will be unmarshaled as `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: @insanePi https://go.dev/play/p/Nv6y0_3TQ2v

Comment: @insanePi while using `interface{}`, there is always an underlying type that we do not yet know of. Here unmarshalling assigns a `map[string]interface{}` as the nested value of the parent map, where an interface is expected(since we can assign any value to an interface type, this is still valid). Interface type kinda wraps around the assigned map value without losing the original type information. Check out https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection if you are unsure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

A Working example: https://go.dev/play/p/02YzI5cv8vV

The whole reason the original response from Burak Serdar was not valid in my opinion is that it does not take into account the fact that you would need to handle the rest of the params as well. If you look closely enough, then you see that the expression is not an array of strings, its of varying type. This implementation handles the custom Unmarshalling and stores all the extra parameters in the Extra field.

Also code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

const jsonPayload = "{\"add\": [{\"var\": [\"100\"]}, \"200\"]}"

func main() {

    data := MathExpressions{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonPayload), &data)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to unmarshal json, error:", err)
        return
    }

    log.Println(data)

    for operation, expression := range data {
        log.Print("Op:", operation, "Exp:", expression)
    }

    log.Println("Finished..")
}

/**
The sub definition for a specific expression in the object
*/
type ExpressionDefinition struct {
    Vars  []string `json:"var"`
    Extra []string
}

func (e *ExpressionDefinition) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    tokens := make([]interface{}, 0)
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tokens)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, token := range tokens {
        log.Println("Processing token:", token, "type:", reflect.TypeOf(token))
        switch token.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            for _, v := range token.(map[string]interface{})["var"].([]interface{}) {
                e.Vars = append(e.Vars, v.(string))
            }
        case string:
            e.Extra = append(e.Extra, token.(string))
        }
    }

    log.Println(tokens)
    return nil
}

/**
The main expressions object which contains all the sub-expressions.
*/
type MathExpressions map[string]ExpressionDefinition
```